# Sublisting Aggregations Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hi I wanted to know if after applying an aggregation can I only select a range of values to return in response. Suppose aggregation has100 docs can I select say documents from 10 to 30 or 0 to 20, etc. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch supports filtering aggregation values with partitioning.

```
GET /_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "expired_sessions": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "account_id",
            "include": {
               "partition": 0,
               "num_partitions": 20
            },
            "size": 10000,
            "order": {
               "last_access": "asc"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "last_access": {
               "max": {
                  "field": "access_date"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

See [Filtering Values with partitions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions).

Be aware that partitioning may add a performance hit depending upon the aggregation.